# Set A Button to addClass of Text Within <TD> By an ID#?

Tags: jquery

So I have a table. First column is user-editable text (ID `#idea01`), and the next two columns have a button each with their own individual ID (`#happy01` & `#unwanted01`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <p>Step 1: Write a list</p>
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td id="idea01" contenteditable="true">&#149; [delete this and enter your idea]</td>
                <td><button id="happy01">happy to do this for life</button></td>
                <td><button id="unwanted01">unwanted dependency</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The idea is that the user can edit the first column text, then click either button, and the CSS will show them which ideas are ".happy" and which ideas are ".unwanted".

The CSS class formatting is simple, and just applies to the text:

```
.happy { color: green; font-weight: bold;}
.unwanted { color: red; text-decoration: line-through;}
```

**My question:**
How do I use jQuery to, on click of button `#happy01`, the `.happy` class is added to TD with ID `#idea01`? Or, on click of button `#unwanted01`, the `.unwanted` class is added to TD `#idea01`?

I thought this would work, but clicking the button does not do anything:

```
$("#happy01").click(function(){
  $("#idea01").addClass("happy");
});

$("#unwanted01").click(function(){
  $("#idea01").addClass("unwanted");
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/m7UJT/ . [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820)

Comment: Is this the entire page? Where are you including the style definitions?  I think perhaps you *are* adding the classes - the code is very straightforward - but they're not applying any styles.

Comment: Danny: No, I just provided the absolute bare minimum of my code for sake of complicity. CSS and JS are stored in independent files. MarcioAT helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, just remove another class.

```
$("#happy01").click(function(){
  $("#idea01").addClass("happy");
  $("#idea01").removeClass("unwanted");
});

$("#unwanted01").click(function(){
  $("#idea01").addClass("unwanted");
  $("#idea01").removeClass("happy");
});
```

Comment: That is it! Thanks Marcio. So the absence of removing the "other" class from each selector was the issue.

Comment: Now you may help-me. It's wrong to use "another" at this context? (improving my english) ;) If you can, choose this answer.

Comment: How do I choose this answer? What I mean by "other" is 'unwanted' is the other of 'happy', and 'happy' is the other of 'unwanted'